# Errors when validating XML and DTD

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd

I'm working on a XML file and I'm having issues with it.

Here's the DTD :

```
<!ELEMENT book (bookinfo,chapter*)>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title,section*)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT bookinfo (title,author,copyright)>
<!ELEMENT author (firstname,surname)>
<!ELEMENT copyright (year,holder)>
<!ENTITY % divers "para|programlisting|itemizedlist|orderedlist">
<!ELEMENT section (title,(%divers;)+)>
<!ELEMENT para (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT programlisting (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT holder (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT itemizedlist (listitem+)>
<!ELEMENT orderedlist (listitem+)>
<!ELEMENT listitem (%divers;)+>
```

Here's what I've done so far (Validation is okay with this part)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "simpledocbook.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="docbook.xml" type="application/xml"?>
<book>
<bookinfo>
<title></title>
<author>
<firstname></firstname>
<surname></surname>
</author>
<copyright>
<year></year>
<holder></holder>
</copyright>
</bookinfo>
<chapter>
<title></title>
<section>
<title></title>
<para></para>
<programlisting></programlisting>
</section>
</chapter>
<chapter>
<title></title>
<section>
<title></title>
<para></para>
<programlisting></programlisting>
<itemizedlist></itemizedlist>
<orderedlist></orderedlist>
</section>
</chapter>
</book>
```

My problem occurs when I try to add itemlist, I don't know where I should put it in the code? Everything I try to put it somewhere I get errors.

Can you guys help me finding why it doesn't work?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Here's what I've done so far (Validation is okay with this part)

Validation should not be ok with that part. You should be getting errors about `itemizedlist` and `orderedlist` being incomplete. They require at least 1 `listitem` (which it sounds like you're trying to add).

Here's a modified version that is valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "simpledocbook.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="docbook.xml" type="application/xml"?>
<book>
    <bookinfo>
        <title></title>
        <author>
            <firstname></firstname>
            <surname></surname>
        </author>
        <copyright>
            <year></year>
            <holder></holder>
        </copyright>
    </bookinfo>
    <chapter>
        <title></title>
        <section>
            <title></title>
            <para></para>
            <programlisting></programlisting>
        </section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <title></title>
        <section>
            <title></title>
            <para></para>
            <programlisting></programlisting>
            <itemizedlist>
                <listitem>
                    <para/>
                </listitem>
            </itemizedlist>
            <orderedlist>
                <listitem>
                    <para/>
                </listitem>
            </orderedlist>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

I added empty `para` elements to the `listitem`'s because at least 1 of the following are required: `para`, `programlisting`, `itemizedlist` or `orderedlist`